# Searching from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I am trying to build an AJAX search form for a dataset that queries an open data API and displays search results below the form. I want to include one or more inputs that correspond to fields within my selected JSON dataset.

When the form is submitted I want to use the form data to query the Open Data API. I want to allow users to find a subset of records from a specific dataset.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="what you are looking for?">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let x = document.getElementById('input');
let obj;

fetch('https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
    obj = JSON.parse(data)
  })
```

This is my code. I want the user to search by the location name and then the whole information will be displayed meaning `observationid`, `observationtime`, `thingid` and `locationname` in the form of a table. Only for the specific `locationname` entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need for searching in the loaded JSON data, you'll need 3 methods a least.

1. **`init()`.** This method loads the whole JSON from the API for the first time.
2. **`search(inputValue)`.** This method takes the `inputValue` value in order to be used to filter the whole JSON data.

For instance, in my `search()` method, I'm using the [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to turn in lowercase the current string, and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) string method to find records of a location name by the first occurrence of any given character, so you could search by inserting any character of a particular location name.

```
search(inputValue) {
    const results = this.data.filter(x => x.locationname.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    return this.renderTable(results);
  }
```

4. **`renderTable(results)`.** This method has the responsibility to render the filtered data given from the `search(inputValue)` method.

[image]

Here is a small demo where you may see it in action.

```js
class SearchJSON {
  data = null;
  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }
  init() {
    fetch('https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.data = data;
      });
  }
  search(inputValue) {
    const results = this.data.filter(x => x.locationname.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    return this.renderTable(results);
  }
  renderTable(results) {
    let html = "<table><thead><tr><th>Observation Id</th><th>Observation Time</th><th>Thing Id</th><th>Location Name</th></tr></thead></table><table class=\"result-table\"><tbody>";
    let result = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      result = results[i];
      html += `<tr><td>${result.observationid}</td>
      <td>${result.observationtime}</td>
      <td>${result.thingid}</td>
      <td>${result.locationname}</td>
      <tr>`;
    }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    return html;
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("form");
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const searchJSON = new SearchJSON();
  form.onsubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = searchJSON.search(input.value);
    const formDiv = document.querySelector("form div");
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = result;
    if (formDiv !== null) {
      formDiv.parentElement.removeChild(formDiv);
      form.appendChild(div);
    }
    form.appendChild(div);
  };
};
```

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container table th,
.container table td {
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.result-table {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="what you are looking for?">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

I'm not sure about the capability of the endpoint but I think that It may be good to investigate if the https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json endpoint can receive parameters, therefore you can send parameters to the endpoint with the given form data to return the required data so, you might no need to use the `init()` method from my example to load the whole JSON data at the first time.

**Update: Endpoint with query string parameters:**

I've found a way to use query string parameters as you needed. You may use it in this way:

```
`https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json?locationname=${inputValue}&$limit=${limit}`
```

> **Where:**
>
> **`locationname`** is the location name to search.
>
> **`$limit`** is the max quantity of records to retrieve by the endpoint with the current parameters.

And also, you may use `async`/`await` fetch requests like this:

```
async search(inputValue, limit) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json?locationname=${inputValue}&$limit=${limit}`);
    const results = await response.json();
    return this.renderTable(results);
}
```

You may see it in action here:

```js
class SearchJSON {
  data = null;
  async search(inputValue, limit) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json?locationname=${inputValue}&$limit=${limit}`);
    const results = await response.json();
    return this.renderTable(results);
  }
  renderTable(results) {
    let html = "<table><thead><tr><th>Observation Id</th><th>Observation Time</th><th>Thing Id</th><th>Location Name</th></tr></thead></table><table class=\"result-table\"><tbody>";
    let result = null;
    for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      result = results[i];
      html += `<tr><td>${result.observationid}</td>
      <td>${result.observationtime}</td>
      <td>${result.thingid}</td>
      <td>${result.locationname}</td>
      <tr>`;
    }
    html += "</tbody></table>";
    return html;
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("form");
  const txtLimit = document.getElementById("txtLimit");
  const input = document.getElementById("input");
  const searchJSON = new SearchJSON();
  form.onsubmit = async(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const result = await searchJSON.search(input.value, txtLimit.value);
    const formDiv = document.querySelector("form div");
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = result;
    if (formDiv !== null) {
      formDiv.parentElement.removeChild(formDiv);
      form.appendChild(div);
    }
    form.appendChild(div);
  };
};
```

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.container table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container table th,
.container table td {
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
  width: 100px;
}

.result-table {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="txtLimit" step="10" max="1000" min="0" value="10">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="what you are looking for?">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I limit the result to only 100? I was trying to use this code                                                                                                                                         let locationname = 'St. James East'; // This would actually be coming from the form input.
const apiUrl = 'https://data.winnipeg.ca/resource/f58p-2ju3.json?' +
                `$where=locationname LIKE '%${locationname}%'` +
                '&$limit=100';
const encodedURL = encodeURI(apiUrl);

Comment: @mina I updated my answer with a new example. Check it out and let me know if this works for you, please.

Comment: Thank you @Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez

Answer (score -1):

1. assign JSON to variable and use $.getJSON
2. use below code with your search button,

   $("#search").on('keypress keyup change input', function() {
   var arrival = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

   ```
    $('#matches').text(!arrival.length ? '' : 

        dataArr.filter(function(place) {

            // look for the entry with a matching `code` value

            return (place.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(arrival) !== -1);

        }).map(function(place) {

            // get titles of matches

            return place.title;

        }).join('\n')); // create one text with a line per matched title
   ```

   });

Comment: 1st observation? Why jQuery ? OP doesn't mention anything related to jQuery here. Installing it just for the getJSON() function is overkill . 2nd of all . Where do you get place.title property? From the provided json file no `title` property exists